# How to pass input value to a multi-step form php

Tags: php, forms, session, multi-step

I've got 2 forms. The information and certain fields from form 1 are also found on form 2, saving the user from having to enter the same data twice. The form 2 has a multi-step form, and I can only display the information in step 1, while the other information is in step 3. This is a problem because form 2 has a multi-step form. By the way, the form I'm using is a Contact Form 7 form, and I'll be providing that information to the Booking Form, which will show it using a shortcode. I'm using session here as well.

i use this function to get the data from cf7

**custom-function.php**

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail',
  function( $contact_form, &$abort, $submission ) {

    $date_445 = $submission->get_posted_data('date_445');
    $pick_time = $submission->get_posted_data('pick_time');
    $customer_name = $submission->get_posted_data('customer_name');
    $customer_lname = $submission->get_posted_data('customer_lname');
    //other fields below
   

    $_SESSION['cf7_data'] = array(
        'date_445' => $date_445,
        'pick_time' => $pick_time,
        'customer_name' => $customer_name,
        'customer_lname' => $customer_lname,
    );
  },
  10, 3
);
```

and this is the booking form(shortcode) this is where i will get the value posted by the contact form

**booking.php**

```
$date_445 = isset($_SESSION['cf7_data']['date_445']) ? $_SESSION['cf7_data']['date_445'] : '';
  $pick_time = isset($_SESSION['cf7_data']['pick_time']) ? $_SESSION['cf7_data']['pick_time'] : '';
  $customer_name = isset($_SESSION['cf7_data']['customer_name']) ? $_SESSION['cf7_data']         ['customer_name'] : '';
  $customer_lname = isset($_SESSION['cf7_data']['customer_lname']) ? $_SESSION['cf7_data']['customer_lname'] : '';


  <script>
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   let fields = {
   dateField: document.querySelector('input[name="name_of_date_input"]'),
   timeField: document.querySelector('input[name="name_of_time_input"]'),
   firstNameField: document.querySelector('input[name="name_of_username_input"]'),
   lastNameField:document.querySelector('input[name="name_of_userlastname_input"]'),
   };
    // date and time are in the first step of the booking form                   
   if (!fields.dateField.value) {
      fields.dateField.value = <?php echo esc_js($date_445) ; ?>";
       }
   if (!fields.timeField.value) {
      fields.timeField.value = "<?php echo esc_js($pick_time) ; ?>";
      }
  // names are in the 3rd step of the form
   if (!fields.firstNameField.value) {
      fields.pickField.value = "<?php echo esc_js($pickup_location) ; ?>";
      }
     if (!fields.lastNameField.value) {
      fields.dropField.value = "<?php echo esc_js($drop_location) ; ?>";
     }  });
    </script>

    <?php
    echo do_shortcode('[booking_form_id="10"]');
    ?>
```

the booking form uses ajax when you input something and click the next button it will get the information and saves in the browser. i am getting the date and time in the first step the only problem is in the 3rd step the data is not populated. Any suggestion will be much appreciated Thank you!

Comment: Have you verified that you are actually able to read the values from the session, in booking.php?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the response. i actually do a var_dump in the booking.php to see the posted data if it's actually passing to the booking page the data is being pass and i am able to fetch it in the 1st step.

Comment: Okay, and where exactly is the problem now? What exactly is preventing you from fetching it in step 3 instead?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out right now to why the other data is not fetching in the 3rd step.  and also i see error in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')" and it is referring to the firstNameField.  maybe this error is the one that preventing the data to be fetch.

Comment: I can see where there could be a problem because the first and last name fields are not completely loaded on the page, which could be the cause of the issue "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting "value")". The firstname and lastname fields on the booking form are wrapped in a div that is hidden and only appear when you click the next button since the booking form uses ajax to display those fields.